# How to include cordova plugin email composer

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, email, phonegap-plugins

How I must include Cordova email plugin that works correct for PhoneGap Build? I am new in mobile apps development and I am using Framework7 and it's very confused…

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer#examples

First I add `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" version="0.8.3" source="npm" />` into config.xml file because I using PhoneGap build, but then I don't know how to continue... I had the plugin but I don't know how to use it... any help? Were I put code bellow? I have no idea, maybe my-app.js (I were tring but probaly I wasn't useing right)

```
window.plugin.email.open({
    to:      ['max.mustermann@appplant.de'],
    cc:      ['erika.mustermann@appplant.de'],
    bcc:     ['john.doe@appplant.com', 'jane.doe@appplant.com'],
    subject: 'Hello World!',
    body:    '<h3>TEST</h3><h2>TEST</h2><h1>TEST</h1>',
    isHtml:  true
});
```

I tryed many things but not got any good solution... I can send my code.

I'd like to do that when I clik on button I send mail on email written in form. (simply)

Any help/advice will be welcome! Tnx!

Comment: Are you checking for device ready event first ?

Comment: Yes, I checked! But still I don't know how to continue? What I put in function onDevice ready event?

Comment: wrap it with `try-catch` block and see what does that error say.

Comment: You can call `email.open` for testing purpose on `deviceready` event.

Comment: `$$(document).on('deviceready', function(){
  myApp.alert("ready");
  cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
       function (isAvailable) {
        myApp.alert("isAvailable");
        cordova.plugins.email.open({
            to:      'max@mustermann.de',
            cc:      'erika@mustermann.de',
            bcc:     ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com'],
            subject: 'Greetings',
            body:    'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig'
        });
       }
   );
  });`

Comment: I added this code to my code my-app.js and it works ok in my browser when I test app (localhost), but when I did PhoneGap build and installed in Android phone the program didn't open any email... any advice?

Comment: On Android not open email to send but still I get alert "ready" and "isAvailable"... look up the code..

Answer (score 0):

It was `'window.plugins.email.open"` and you had `"window.plugin.email.open"`.